# What does it mean "Predicates should not modify their state due to a function call"?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, predicate

I was reading online about C++ and came across this statement:

> Predicates should not modify their state due to a function call.

I did not understand what does "state" mean here. Can someone please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Predicate objects passed to functions may get copied an arbitrary number of times (eg recursive quicksort).  If their comparison operation (function call) changed their state each predicate would get a different state.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's consider the algorithm [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) as an example. It traverses a range and counts how often a given predicate evaluates to true. Further assume we want to check how many elements in a container are smaller than a given number, e.g. 5 or 15.

A predicate can be many things. It just has to be callable. It can be a functor:

```
struct check_if_smaller {
    int x;
    bool operator()(int y) const { return y < x; }
};
```

You can create different instances of that predicate, e.g. these two

```
check_if_smaller a{5};
check_if_smaller b{15};
```

can be used to check if numbers are smaller than `5` or `15` respectively:

```
bool test1 = a(3);  // true because 3 < 5
bool test2 = b(20); // false because 20 is not < 15
```

The member `x` is the state of the predicate. Typically this should not change when the predicate is applied (by calling its `operator()`).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)):

> In mathematical logic, a predicate is commonly understood to be a
>   Boolean-valued function P: X→ {true, false}, called the predicate on
>   X. However, predicates have many different uses and interpretations in
>   mathematics and logic, and their precise definition, meaning and use
>   will vary from theory to theory.

Sloppy speaking, a predicate is a function mapping something to a boolean. The fact that we use a functor that is not just a function but a function object with a state can be considered as an implementation detail, and repeatedtly evaluating the same predicate for same input is commonly expected to yield the same result. Also, algorithms make this assumption and nothing really prevents them from copying the predicate you pass (actually [the standard explicitly permits them to do so](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#10.sentence-1)). If evaluating the predicate would alter its internal state, the algorithm may not work as expected.

Comment: You mean anyone should avoid changing x while the predicate is executing, right? Is it OK to make x private and have a setX(...) method instead to control everything?

Comment: @Gupta `a` models the predicate "check if a number is smaller than 5". If you change its `x` member it is a different predicate. Of course you can make `x` private, though I dont see how this makes any difference or what would be the advantage

Comment: I would additionally suggest to make the predicate function-call operator `const`, if it does not modify it's state: `bool operator()(int y) const { return y < x; }`.

Comment: And, here is a link to the relevant note in the Standard: [Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely.](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#10.sentence-1).

Comment: @DanielLangr awesome, I'll edit it into the answer, just dont have the time right now

Comment: In the specific case of `count_if`, is the predicate allowed to change the global state and change the return value accordingly? `count_if` does work with input iterators, which means it can't evaluate each element more than once.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I don't think that there is anything that would actually forbid that. Note that the question is about "why should not" (and the answer is a little handwavy ;). Though afaik there is no guarantee on the order in which the algorithm passes the elements and that might affect that global state

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili and don't miss Daniels comment: " Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely."

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 If it's an input iterator, how could the order be different than the regular begin to end each element evaluated once consecutively?

Answer (score 11):

In laymen terms, a *state* in a predicate is a data member. A predicate changing the state means that the member get's changed during the algorithm execution and that change is going to affect predicate behavior.

The reason to avoid this is the fact that algorithms are under no obligation to keep a single instance of a predicate. They might easily be copied around, and state changed in one copy, will not be shared with a state in another copy. As a result, program will behave unexpectedly (for someone expecting the state change to be in effect).

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what standard says that predicate should act  like a pure function (in mathematical terms), i.e. its returning value should be dependent on input alone.

The mention of state because predicates can be copied or can be invoked in different threads, which depends on implementation and platform behavior. For lambda's and other invokable objects which aren't functions this may mean unordered access to the storage, captured by reference, or access different values if they were captured by value. For a function, it means that any side-effects (including change of static variables) may result in problems.

If a predicate for sorting would return different results for same pair, then some sort algorithms become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, many of the algorithms that take predicates don't promise any particular traversal order (the *ExecutionPolicy* overloads allow for interleaved traversal). You might get different answers to the same question.

If there are multiple threads calling<sup>1</sup> the predicate and it changes some shared value, that's [a data race](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races), i.e. undefined behaviour.

1. or one thread interleaving calls to